# template: is an incomplete or empty template

Tags: go, go-templates, gomail

I have a following piece of code in which i am trying to send an email using `gopkg.in/gomail.v2`. I am perfectly able to send the email when the email template is placed in the root directory of the project like this

```
./
    main.go
    template.html
```

```
// Info defines
type Info struct {
    Age  int
    Name string
}

func (i Info) sendMail() {
    fp := filepath.Join("template.html")

    t := template.New(fp)

    var err error
    t, err = t.ParseFiles(fp)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    var tpl bytes.Buffer
    if err := t.Execute(&tpl, i); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    result := tpl.String()
    // ... email sending logic
}

func main() {
    info := &Info{
        Name: "name 1",
        Age:  20,
    }

    info.sendMail()
}
```

but when i change the template directory to `emails/template.html` and change the filepath to 

`fp := filepath.Join("emails", "template.html")` 

then I get the error from `t.Execute()` 
`template: "emails/template.html" is an incomplete or empty template`

I have also tried 
`fp, _ := filepath.Abs("emails/template.html")`

but got error

`template: "/mnt/data/go/test/emails/template.html" is an incomplete or empty template`
 the path mentioned is correct though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed

```
if err := t.Execute(&tpl, i); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
```

to

```
if err := t2.ExecuteTemplate(&tpl, "template.html", i); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
```

and it worked

If I want to use `t.Execute(&tpl, i)` instead, then I have to specify the templates name as filename while creating the template

`t := template.New("template.html")`